# How to get value php on ajax script onclick function using <a href [FINISH]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

page one.php

code javascript: for call the function

```
    <script>               
    function chartmin(event) {
    var mn = event.target.value;
    var request = $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "two.php",   
            data: {mn: mn}
           });

        request.done( function( msg ) {
            $("#myboxmin").html(msg); 
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
    </script>
```

This my php code:

```
    <?php
    include '../koneksi.php';


    $q=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id_bab,name_bab FROM nama_pasal_topik") or die (mysql_error());
    while($qq=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        $id_bab=array();
        $id_bab[]=$qq['id_bab'];
        $bab=$qq['id_bab'];
        $nama_bab=$qq['name_bab'];
        echo "<font color='blue'>".$bab."-->".$nama_bab."</font><br>";
    ?>


    <a href="#" class="leftlinks" id="mn" name="mn" onclick="chartmin(event);"  value="<?php echo $bab; ?>"><?php echo $nama_bab; ?></a>

    <?php
    }
?>
```

Then I want to data print on this div

```
  <div id="myboxmin">
  </div> <!--tutup mybox-->
```

page two.php

```
  <?php

   $mn = $_GET['mn'];
   echo $mn."tez"; 
  ?>
```

I want to use `onclick` event but I want to using `a href`. May you know how do it?

Comment: What is not working ? `event.preventDefault()` is needed to prevent default behaviour of `anchor tag`

Comment: where i put event.preventDefault() ? @RayonDabre

Comment: In your function implementation..

Comment: @tara - has [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32681179/4120911)  helped you?

Comment: i finish it .. but .. i want to try your solution .. wait .. @CliffBurton

Comment: Any news @tara? I've edited my answer, in the `data-hash` attribute's content you have to put an hash `data-hash="#yourHash"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is HIJAX (take a look at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijax))

Basically, as @RayonDabre said in his comment, you have to prevent the default behaviour of the `a` element.

Listen on `a` elements and prevent its behaviour with `preventDefault()`

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: yourData,
        type: "get"
    });
});
```

You may want to add a hash to the location url to keep track of the navigation with this inside the AJAX's `success` callback (or `request.done(function()...` in your case).

```
window.location.hash = hash;
```

where the `hash` variable contains the `data-hash` attribute that you can add on the `a` elements

```
<a href="someUrl.php" data-hash="#hashElement">Link</a>
```

You can retrieve the `data-hash` value with this

```
var hash = $(this).data("hash");
```